# Generating a 'secret' 2-digit number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

I'm coding a game to play with people who are in the same room together. As part of this game, one player is given a (uniformly) randomly chosen number between 0 and 99. The other players must guess as close as possible to this secret number based on some clues.

The challenge is that I want all players to be looking at a single screen. So I can't just display the number, since this would ruin the game. Instead, I need a way for only one person to know the number. I am not worried about players cheating.

One idea was to display something like '$2.41$^ $3.81$'. The chosen player could use a calculator to evaluate this, and the secret number might be the first two decimal places (in this case 54). If I chose this approach, I can't think of a nice way to find numbers that will give me anything from 0 to 99 uniformly.

Can you get this approach to work or think of a better strategy?

Comment: Sounds like this may be better for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was trying to figure out where this should go ... I'll cross-post there!

Comment: If you aren't worried about cheating, display some triple like $(a,b,c)$ of natural numbers, to mean "take digits $b$ and $c$ of $\sin (n)$" .  Thus, since $\sin (5)=-0.958924274663$, the triple $(5,2,6)$ would yield $54$.  At least that's roughly uniform between $0$ and $99$.

Comment: If you aren't worried about cheating just ask everyone else to turn around.

Comment: To avoid the issue of cheating altogether, you might have the special person privately enter a number $n$ (of their choice) between $0$ and $100$  and then if the machine displays the number $m$, the special person interprets it as $(m+n)\pmod {101}$.  Not sure if that sort of mechanism is allowed in your game.

Comment: Have the picker write down the clock time at a specific time on his watch. Convert the minutes and seconds to seconds only and render that result modulo 100.